# I want to implement capture and sharing captured image

Tags: android, share, capture

I want to capture and share a view as an image.
My code runs without errors. The sharing part works well, but the capture does not work.
Any help is welcome.

Here the code i use.

```
linel1.buildDrawingCache();
Bitmap captureView = linel1.getDrawingCache();
FileOutputStream fos;
try {
   fos = new FileOutputStream(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/capture.jpeg");
   captureView.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,  "title");
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/DCIM/capture.jpeg"));
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "This picture is shared"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget `linel1.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` before `linel1.buildDrawingCache();`

You can read more about drawing cache in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11448898/4170584) on SO.